# Akka cluster detecting Quarantined state

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

How can I detect Quarantined state from within the system being quarantined~?

I'm seeing this log below:

`[warn] Remoting - Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://Application@192.168.0.15:6000]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: The remote system has quarantined this system. No further associations to the remote system are possible until this system is restarted.`

but I'm not sure how I can react to this from code.

---

I found this thread: [Recovering from the Quarantined state](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/sC9PBkC2SME/m_1muhuPqTwJ), suggesting to listen for the `QuarantinedEvent` but that is not dispatched on the system *being quarantined*.

And I actually listened for all `RemotingLifecycleEvent`s and found this:

`AssociationError [akka.tcp://Application@192.168.0.100:2552] -> [akka.tcp://Application@192.168.0.15:6000]: Error [Invalid address: akka.tcp://Application@192.168.0.15:6000] [akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://Application@192.168.0.15:6000
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.Transport$InvalidAssociationException: The remote system has quarantined this system. No further associations to the remote system are possible until this system is restarted.]`

but that is just an `AssociationError` which will be dispatched for many other reasons as well, do I have to search for the actual text `"The remote system has quarantined this system."` within the error to be sure??

Comment: in flink's usage of akka, you'll find it matches the actual text to decide whether it is quarantined.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, what you suggested works and can be done as follows

Subscribe an actor to `akka.remote.AssociationErrorEvent`

```
override def preStart(): Unit = {
  context.system.eventStream.subscribe(self, classOf[akka.remote.AssociationErrorEvent])
}
```

and then do following in the `receive` method

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case e:AssociationErrorEvent =>
    log.info(s"AssociationErrorEvent: $e")
    if (e.cause.getCause.getMessage.contains("quarantined this system")) {
      log.warning(s"We got quarantined")
    }
}
```

Comment: Since 2.4.2 there is the `ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent` ([source](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.2/akka-remote/src/main/scala/akka/remote/RemotingLifecycleEvent.scala#L92)).

Answer (score 3):

Following  William Carter comment:

Akka provides appropriate event that does not require check of the message content.

```
class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    super.preStart()
    context.system.eventStream.subscribe(context.self, classOf[ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent])
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case ev: ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent => log.warning(s"I was quarantined by ${ev.remoteAddress}")
  }
}
```